# Real Memory VS. Private Memory

Tags: macos, memory

I have an Objective-C application that is designed to run for an extended period of time using WebKit views. After time the application builds up a fair amount of memory so I would like to accurately reveal the memory usage to the end user upon request. In Activity Monitor on OS X I see two memory values for my application Real Memory and Private Memory. From what I have read Private is everything that the process has and Real is an estimate. What should I trust? Is there a specific formula I can use to calculate the exact usage rather than what OS X reports?

Not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 6):

If you are worried about memory leaks, you should be using [the various tools provided by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001883-CJBJFIDD) to debug it.

Real memory is the actual physical memory in use by the process.

Private memory is the physical memory that is used by just that process.

Virtual memory is the size of the entire virtual memory of the process including those pages that are not currently resident in physical RAM.

It's actually quite difficult to tell by looking at those numbers if you have a leak.  For example, a block that is malloced and then leaked will never be referenced again, so it'll eventually get swapped out.  It'll be part of the virtual memory but not part of the resident memory.  So if you have a leak, the virtual memory will gradually increase over time.

On the other hand, virtual memory will increase if malloc can't find an unused block of memory to allocate, but it won't decrease when free gives memory back.  So if you malloc a huge amount of RAM the VM will increase but even if you then free it correctly, it'll never decrease again.  If you also have a leak, it will take a long time for malloc to run out of the recycled VM which means that you might not notice it.

So, use the purpose built leak detection tools.